# Obtaining Spring Boot SessionFactory results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am getting `NullpointerException` trying to get `SessionFactory` in Spring Boot using properties file:

**application.properties:**

```
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databseName
db.username=root
db.password= 
 
# Hibernate
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none
entitymanager.packagesToScan=com
```

My Configuration file -- I have created another configuration file besides Spring Boot's default configuration file. I don't want to mix them together.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})
@ComponentScan({"com"})    
public class Configuration {
        @Value("${db.driver}")
        private String DRIVER;
        
        @Value("${db.password}")
        private String PASSWORD;
        
        @Value("${db.url}")
        private String URL;
        
        @Value("${db.username}")
        private String USERNAME;
        
        @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
        private String DIALECT;
     
        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
        private String SHOW_SQL;
     
        @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
        private String HBM2DDL_AUTO;
     
        @Value("${entitymanager.packagesToScan}")
        private String PACKAGES_TO_SCAN;
        
        public Configuration() {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
        
        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource(){
            DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
            //dataSource.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);
            dataSource.setUrl(URL);
            dataSource.setUsername(USERNAME);
            dataSource.setPassword(PASSWORD);
            System.out.println("CALLING ...................... DATASOURCE ..........");
            return dataSource;
        }
        
        @Bean
        public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
            LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
            sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
            sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
            Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
            System.out.println("CALLING ...................... LocalSessionFactoryBean ....1......");
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", DIALECT);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", SHOW_SQL);
            hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", HBM2DDL_AUTO);
            sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties);
            System.out.println("CALLING ...................... LocalSessionFactoryBean ......2....");
            return sessionFactory;
        }
    
    }
```

The Print statement in `dataSource()` is shown in the console but the print statements in `sessionFactory()` is never displayed.
Should `sessionFactory()` be called somewhere in the code?

My Utility class is:

```
public class HibernateUtility {

    @Autowired  
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

I think putting `@Autowired` should be able to call `sessionFactory()` in `Configuration` but that is not the case here.

My DAO methods to open and close session are:

```
public abstract class PromoHibernateDAOImpl{


// ANY OF THE FIRST TWO LINES IN THIS METHOD GIVES **NullPointerException**
// One is in comment
public void openCurrentSession(){
        //this.currentSession = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        this.currentSession = HibernateUtility.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        currentTransaction = currentSession.beginTransaction();
    }
    
    public void closeCurrentSession(){
        if(currentSession != null && currentTransaction != null){
            currentTransaction.commit();
            currentSession.close();
        }
    }

}
```

Any of the first two lines in `openCurrentSession()` gives `NullPointerException`.

I tried each one separately. I think the method `LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()` in my configuration never get executed and because of that the `"sessionFactory"` in the utility class is never initialized, though that method also has `@Bean`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should sessionFactory() be called somewhere in the code ---> Not exactly, since you have `@Bean` it should be called by the framework when the application starts. Start your springboot application in debug mode and see if the controll reaches sessionfactory() method

Comment: `@Autowired` doesn't work on `static` fields. Also why are you trying so hard to work around Spring Boot?  Wy use native hibernate instead of JPA (with the latter you have zero configuration). Not to mention that your dao implementation is seriously flawed...

Comment: @M.Deinum Can you share more light on the flawed DAO implementation so that i can rectify it. Thank you

Comment: Dao is singleton. Imagine 10 requests coming in, as you are keeping state in your dao (the current session and transaction) which one do you think will survive with 10 concurrent requests. Nonetheless why do you need plain hibernate, generally with the current version of JPA you don't really need native hibernate anymore. And if you must you can still `unwrap` the `Session` from the `EntityManager` for those corner cases. IMHO you are complicating things with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: HibernateUtility is not bean also